# android webview -youtube embed not working

Tags: android, html

Hi i am trying to embed an youtube video in android. 
This is what shows up on screen -https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpjWS.jpg

This is my code for webview

```
<img src="illustration.jpg" />
<video src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvWy9NXiZZI"  width="320" height="240" autobuffer controls onclick="this.play();"/>
```

The image shows up fine but the video below the image doesn't show up , neither does it play when i click on it.

Can any body please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

This small addition to the Application level in the manifest does the trick:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution.

Just use Iframe .

```
<iframe width="350" height="240" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you enable javascript in your webview?
if not
try this, here I am enabling javascript

```
WebView web=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvWy9NXiZZI");
```

This is the xml

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.webkit.WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</android.webkit.WebView>
```

Also there is an issue that the videos cannot be played in some devices due to limitted hardware resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.house"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

try to put "xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

and android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in your manifest

```
<activity android:name="Main_Webview" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/vc1CClG   .Still doesnt work for me. I have changed manifest as you had said.

Comment: try to check into your Project Properties > Android if your build target is higher that 3.0 or honeycomb